# Continuity Proof of $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: limits, continuity

I am trying to prove a simple problem that the function $y= \sqrt{x}$ is continuous by using the fact that if $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) = 0$ then the function will be continuous. My proof goes:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0} \sqrt{x+\Delta x}-\sqrt{x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}} $$

If $x>0$, then $\mathbf{when}$ $|\Delta x| < x$:

$$0 \leq\frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}}  \leq \frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$$0 \leq \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}}  \leq \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Since the $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x}} = 0$ then $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}} = 0$ 
QED

Is this correct?

Comment: How exactly do you conclude $$\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}}  \leq \frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x}}$$ from $|\Delta x|<x$? This doesn't appear clear to me at all from your way of presentation.

Comment: Its not a conclusion, when/assuming $|\Delta x| < x$ You can make the assumption since $|\Delta x| --> 0$ so eventually the inequality will satisfy $|\Delta x| < x$.

Comment: Okay, I might have to rephrase my concern: where does the *inequality* $$\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x}+\sqrt{x}}\color{red}{\leq} \frac{|\Delta x|}{\sqrt{x}}$$ comes from? Could you elaborate on the steps involved leading to this inequality as this is the crucial step.

Comment: Oh my apologies.  By setting up this inequality, and showing that the right hand side is zero (knowing $1/\sqrt{x}$ for any $x$ is defined when $x>0$), I can then show that the lim of the middle term is zero. This then demonstrates continuity by the first statement with the general $f(x)$

Comment: I think @mrtaurho is asking WHY this equality holds. It's not clear why $|\Delta x| < x$ would imply this inequality.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I see my error now. I mistyped something. Though I am not sure if my proof works now since  I am not taking into account $\Delta x < 0$

Comment: *Sigh*. Yes, I understand your argument and its completely correct, *given* that the inequality actually holds. And that the crux, I'm unable for myself to derive the inequality from the assumption of $|\Delta x|<x$ as *Célio Augusto* pointed out.

Comment: The denominator is a sum of two positive numbers so the inequality is trivial (though you probably want an absolute value on the left hand side).

Comment: The assumption $|\Delta x|\lt x$ isn't really needed; its only role, as I see it, is to ensure that $x+\Delta x$ is nonnegative, so that $\sqrt{x+\Delta x}$ is a real number.

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser yes that is were the inequality is coming from. Is it an incorrect step in this proof since mrtaurho is stating it is unclear?

Comment: @RadekMartinez It's not incorrect, it was just not clear to me and it might be better to improve this passage with further details.